# Bookmarklet to extract text offset from specific HTML tags

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, text-parsing

I want to write a bookmarklet to automate search I do on a specific Web page.

I need to look for the string “**IP Cliente** :", go to the next line and extract the IP number from the string “93.103.61.18”.

Then I want to feed the IP number to the Geocities Web site 
http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&IpAddress=93.103.61.18
to obtain Country and City and display them in a box on top of the initial Web page. Here too the Country and City can be extracted by looking for a particular combination of text and HTML tags, and grabbing text at a particular offset from that position. For example 
"Country"

I looked for libraries of bookmarklets around but I have not found an example I can modify. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Finding an existing bookmarklet to get such specific text is going to be next to impossible.

However there are *many* bookmarklets that will do a search using text you have selected. So all you have to do is select the IP address, then click the bookmarklet. These are relatively simple. Just search for "google bookmarklet" or "search bookmarklet" and find hundreds. You'll quickly find one you can modify.